# Pigpio reading sensor returning -83”i2c read failed”

Tags: gpio, i2c, sensor, pigpio

I am testing using my new air quality 5 click sensor with my Raspberry Pi
(https://www.mikroe.com/air-quality-5-click)
using command line.

When I enter `i2cdetect -y 1`it appears at address 48.

Then when I enter `pigs i2co 1 0x30 0` It returns 0 as usual.

However when I try `pigs i2crd 0 1` It returns

`ERROR: I2C read failed
-83`

I am not sure how many bytes the returned data is supposed to be, but there does not appear to be any being returned. I have tried a range of lengths(0-9, 0-122) and the error message did not change.

I am using a Raspberry Pi zero W V1.1 that has successfully used these same commands to get data from the previous version of this sensor (2 click) and I can’t find any other people who have had the same problem online. I have tried killall then restarting with pigpiod but no change.

Comment: It looks like the sensor contains more than one 16 bit register.  So you probably need to select a register then read from it.  E.g. to select register 3 and read 2 bytes try "pigs i2cwd 0 3 i2crd 0 2"

Comment: That returns -82 write failed then -83 read failed

Comment: I think you'll have to give a link to the device specs (if there is such a thing).  I had a quick look at the software but it was contained in an unreadable to me mpkg format,

Comment: What specs exactly? I have provided a link to the website that has the data sheets on it

Comment: The I2C registers to read/write to use the device.

Comment: This? void applicationTask()
{
 NO2_sensorData = airq5_readSensorData(_AIRQ5_DATA_CHANNEL_NO2);
 NH3_sensorData = airq5_readSensorData(_AIRQ5_DATA_CHANNEL_NH3);
 CO_sensorData = airq5_readSensorData(_AIRQ5_DATA_CHANNEL_CO);

Comment: There’s more but can’t fit in comment

Comment: Do you know the values of _AIRQ5_DATA_CHANNEL_NO2 and the I2C commands used by airq5_readSensorData?

Comment: No, I have no real knowledge of that side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor that you are using has 3 lines from the MICS6814 air quality sensor connected to the ADC which is ADS1015 and this is what is connected to the Pi over I2C. 
**[image: strong text]**
I do not think you can read from this ADC directly from the shell however there are python scripts available to read from the ADC. You can install the python libraries [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15) and try out [this example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15) and see if it works for you (Please use the ADS1015 in the code by uncommenting line 15 and commenting out line 11). What you want is the data from channel 0,1 and 2 which should give you the sensor values.

Comment: i have a version working now thank you for helping and sorry for not replying at the time